# How to save JSON key data to Python Variables

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

is there a way to store my JSON key data(id,name,price...) on each of my variable(id1-id3, id1-id3, price1-price3...)

here is my sample code

```
import json

from kivy.properties import StringProperty

f = open('sample.json')
data = json.load(f)

id1 = StringProperty(None)
id2 = StringProperty(None)
id3 = StringProperty(None)

name1 = StringProperty(None)
name2 = StringProperty(None)
name3 = StringProperty(None)

price1 = StringProperty(None)
price2 = StringProperty(None)
price3 = StringProperty(None)

quantity1  = StringProperty(None)
quantity2  = StringProperty(None)
quantity3  = StringProperty(None)

for i in data:
    print(i)
```

and here is the JSON file

```
[
  {
    "id": "p01",
    "name": "Name 1",
    "price": 1,
    "quantity": 1
  },
  {
    "id": "p02",
    "name": "Name 2",
    "price": 2,
    "quantity": 2
  },
  {
    "id": "p03",
    "name": "Name 3",
    "price": 3,
    "quantity": 3
  }
]
```

i'm planning to use bigger data. but for simplicity's sake, i just use 3 items as an example

Comment: Why do you want to use variables? You can simply convert JSON to Python dictionary with json.loads().

Comment: @MuhammadYousufNoor, I will be using this variables in the future, so i need to extract the individual data like name, price, and quantity from the JSON file. I'm relatively new to JSON module so please bare with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to store each value of JSON in a new variable, you can use a python dictionary.

See [JSON and Python Dictionary](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp)

```
import json

#opening json file
with open("data.json") as f:
    #converting json to python dict and stroing it in data variable
    data = json.loads(f.read())

#iterating dict items and printing values
for items in data:
    print(items['id'],items['name'],items['price'])

#you can also access dict values like this
#0 is the index number.
print(data[0]['id'])
print(data[0]['name'])
print(data[0]['price'])

#similarly
print(data[1]['id'])
print(data[2]['id'])
```

Comment: Thank You This Works, Just a follow up question. What if I have another table, how should I access the dict values for table 2? I'll attach the modified JSON code

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use json module with python dictionary as follow:

```
# Import the module
import json

# String with JSON format
data_JSON =  """
[
  {
    "id": "p01",
    "name": "Name 1",
    "price": 1,
    "quantity": 1
  },
  {
    "id": "p02",
    "name": "Name 2",
    "price": 2,
    "quantity": 2
  },
  {
    "id": "p03",
    "name": "Name 3",
    "price": 3,
    "quantity": 3
  }
]
"""

# Convert JSON string to dictionary
data_dict = json.loads(data_JSON)
print(data_dict)
```